# How to add author info to a document in Mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    discussion_id: ObjectId(...),
    slug: '34db',
    posted: ISODateTime(...),
    author: {
              id: ObjectId(...),
              name: 'Rick'
             },
    text: 'This is so bogus ... '
}
```

This is what I did so far:

```
class Discussion
{

   /**
    * @MongoDB\Id
    */
        protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ObjectId
     */
    protected $discussion_id;


   /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $slug;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\String    <---------- IS THIS THE RIGHT DATA TYPE?
     */
    protected $author;

     /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $text;


    /**
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    protected $createdAt;

}
```

So in my code:

```
  $author_info = array(
            "userName" => $userName
            );

        $discussion = new Discussion();
        $discussion->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $discussion->setAuthor($author_info);
        $discussion->setText($listingInquiry);
```

My question is am I doing it right? I have a feeling the author type needs to be something else.  Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: yes doctrone mongo odm (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: I answered - but then thought: Are Authors already stored in a different collection?  that might change how I would store it - not have it generate an ObjectId - instead pass it in.

Comment: Yes the authors are also stored in as users. What would you do different? I mean how would you pass it in?

Comment: pretty simple change - instead of an `$id` as `@MongoDB\Id`, switch it to `@MongoDB\ObjectId` and pass through the original user id - edited the code below.

Comment: You are the man. Thank You for answering. Wish I could give you more points

Comment: one last update - its `new \MongoId()`, not `ObjectId()` if you havent figured that out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an `ObjectId` in your Author, that would be an embedded document ( or you could use a `@MongoDB\Hash` ).

For an embedded document:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Author
{
   /**
    * @MongoDB\ObjectId
    */
   protected $id;

   /**
    * @MongoDB\String
    */
    protected $name;
}
```

In your main document

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="[Namespace]\Author")
 */
 protected $author;
```

In your code:

```
$author = new Author();
$author->setId( new \MongoId( $userId ) );
$author->setName( "Mark" );

$discussion->setAuthor( $author);
```